# How do I make this iridescent wavey material?

Tags: materials, shaders, lighting, caustics

I found this beautiful render consisting of different iridescent glass-like objects. While I understand how to generate this geometry, how would I go about generating this material? Is it in the lighting, the reflection, the caustics?

[image: Reference image]

More of this render can be found [over here](https://www.behance.net/gallery/101677327/Chromaflow?tracking_source=for_you_feed_activity)

Comment: I think it has more to see with the environment and lighting than with the material itself which looks like reflective plastic

Comment: Agreed, I don't think this is iridescent. The central extrusion is not transmissive, just metallic, and it's all in the stylised reflected environment?

Comment: Tip: You can use the search box at the top of the page to search for previous similar questions. https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=iridescent